# Android Uri is null when converting Uri to String

Tags: android, android-intent, uri

I am trying to get the `Uri` (file path) of an image. I am taking from a gallery into an `ImageView` and display that image also in another `NetworkImageView` in the previous Activity (`MainActivity`).

I want the `Filepath` variable to be accessible from anywhere in the code. I am trying to access it in `uploadImage()`. I first initialized it in the `onActivityResult()`. In `uploadImage()`, I am trying to convert the `Uri` to a `String`, so I can send it back to the MainActivity as an `Intent`.

When I run the code, I get a `NullPointerException` in the `uploadImage()` which converts the `Uri` to `String`. Upon debugging, I realized the `Filepath` variable is returning null.
Please can anyone identify whats wrong with the code and suggest a solution?

```
    Uri filePath;
    public void uploadImage() {

        //Showing the progress dialog
        final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Uploading...", "Please wait...", false, false);
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, UPLOAD_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String s) {
                        loading.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(Activity2.this, s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Intent returnIntent = new Intent();

             //Getting a NullPointerException on this line
                        String str = filePath.toString();
                        returnIntent.putExtra("UPDATED_PIC", str);


                        setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
                        finish();

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                        //Dismissing the progress dialog
                        loading.dismiss();
                        //Showing toast
                        Toast.makeText(Activity2.this, volleyError.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                //Converting Bitmap to String
                String image = getStringImage(bitmap);
                //Creating parameters
                Map<String, String> params = new Hashtable<String, String>();

                //Adding parameters
                params.put(KEY_IMAGE, image);


                //returning parameters
                return params;
            }
        };

        //Creating a Request Queue
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        //Adding request to the queue
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            Uri filePath = data.getData();

            try {
                //Getting the Bitmap from Gallery
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
                //Setting the Bitmap to ImageView
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Where assigning value in `filePath` ?

Comment: Change `Uri filePath = data.getData();` to `filePath = data.getData();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

declare  `Uri` filePath as global, then remove `Uri` in `onActivityResult`.

Answer (score 1):

Uri filePath = data.getData();

// Remove Uri from this line . It will fix your issue . Currently you are assigning data.getData() in a local variable so make it global and then access it from upload image